# Merging binary trees, why is t3 not overwritten each time

Tags: python

I have created a function that merges two binary trees together and it's functional. However, I don't understand why t3 isn't overwritten by an empty TreeNode each time the function is called. How can it produce the full merged tree?

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right
class Solution:
    def mergeTrees(self, t1: TreeNode, t2: TreeNode) -> TreeNode:
        t3 = TreeNode()
        if t1 == None:
            return t2
        if t2 == None:
            return t1
        t3.val = t1.val + t2.val
        t3.left = self.mergeTrees(t1.left, t2.left)
        t3.right = self.mergeTrees(t1.right, t2.right)
        return t3
```

Comment: Each iteration of the function has a different `t3`.

Comment: For the same reason that it "wouldn't be overwritten" if you called a different function, and that function had a local variable that coincidentally was also named `t3`.